# Sorting and Grouping List data

Tags: c#, list, linq

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BskTC.png)

I have data like shown in image and have to sort them out based on certain rules

```
a.Customer - Asc
b.Purpose - Asc
c.Year - Desc and if there is no year then it should come at end.
d.Date - Asc
```

This is done correctly using Orderby

```
listdata.Orderby(x=>x.customer).ThenBy(x=>x.Purpose).ThenByDescending(x=>x.year).ThenBy(i=>i.Date)
```

But not I want to add another step to sorting like below

```
a.Customer - Asc
b.Purpose - Asc
c.GroupBy - Purpose (After following a,b points . I want to see above data sorted by Purpose) 
d.Year - Desc and if there is no year then it should come at end.
e.Date - Asc
```

I was trying groupby and found it little tricky any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the GroupBy to the end?  Sort before grouping affects the order of items (including order inside a group), sort after grouping affects the order of groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
listdata
    .Orderby(x=>x.customer)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x=>x.year))
    .Select(group => group.ThenBy(i=>i.Date));
```

and to collect the results into a list:

```
List<List<Data>> result = listdata
    .Orderby(x=>x.customer)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x=>x.year))
    .Select(group => group.ThenBy(i=>i.Date))
    .Select(group => group.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but how to convert this into List as all I get is IOrderedEnumerable data .

Comment: thanks I was able to tweak your code a bit as per my need .
`
List<List<Data>> result = listdata.AsEnumerable()
    .Orderby(x=>x.customer)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Purpose)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x=>x.year))
    .Select(group => group.ThenBy(i=>i.Date))
    .Select(group => group.ToList())
    .ToList(); 
`